# Parsing XML data to php

Tags: php, xml

I have following code and i want to know how to send that XML data to php variable.

```
             $XMLAttendee= "<attendee_list>
        <attendee>
        <attendee_id>1028</attendee_id>
        <screen_name>shahid</screen_name>
                    <language_culture_name>es-ES</language_culture_name>
            </attendee>
                </attendee_list>";
```

So, variable $XMLAttendee hold xml data and pass same to following variable
      $requestParameters["attendee_list"]=$XMLAttendee;

So want i want to know how parse xml data to an php variable

Comment: This isn't a CI question as much as it is a PHP question. Look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: yes, but how do i start parsing xml with php..

Comment: Click the 'Examples' link. There are examples within it. http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use xml_parse_into_struct:

```
<?php
$xml = "
<attendee_list>
    <attendee>
        <attendee_id>1028</attendee_id>
        <screen_name>shahid</screen_name>
        <language_culture_name>es-ES</language_culture_name>
    </attendee>
</attendee_list>";

$parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $xml, $values, $index);
xml_parser_free($parser);

print_r($values);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tag] => ATTENDEE_LIST
            [type] => open
            [level] => 1
            [value] => 

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tag] => ATTENDEE
            [type] => open
            [level] => 2
            [value] => 

        )

    ...
```

Comment: In 2012, surely we can use an object-oriented approach.